# Parameter Data type vs Database Data Type

Tags: c#, sql-server

About parameters SQL data type?

In my SQL Server database table I defined the data type there.

My question is in parameters and database data type they should be the same data type right?

Sample `Enumber` data type is `INT` in SQL Server and in parameter `SqlDataType` is also `INT`?

But when I run it say data type need to convert string to int32?

Is there something wrong in my data type?

Student

```
// Adding data to table Employee from database
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Employee(Enumber,Inumber,Pnumber,Fname,Mname,Sname,Age,Bdate,Gender,Mstatus,Nationality,Eaddress,Cnumber,Picture) Values (@Enumber,@Inumber,@Pnumber,@Fname,@Mname,@Sname,@Age,@Bdate,@Gender,@Mstatus,@Nationality,@Eaddress,@Cnumber,@Picture)";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Enumber",SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtEnumber.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Inumber",SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtInumber.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pnumber",SqlDbType.VarChar,20).Value = txtPassport.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname",SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value =  txtFname.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mname",SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = txtMname.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sname",SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = txtSname.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtAge.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Bdate",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DtpBdate.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender",SqlDbType.VarChar,20).Value = cbGender.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mstatus",SqlDbType.VarChar,20).Value = cbMstatus.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nationality",SqlDbType.VarChar,30).Value = txtNationality.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Eaddress",SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value =  txtEAddress.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cnumber",SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtCnumber.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Picture",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  ImageToBase64(PbImage.Image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: the value in 10000 and sql server data type is INT thats way i make INT also in my Parameters?

Comment: `SqlDbType.Int` is already `Int32`. What is the error, paste the exact error here.

Comment: Failed To Convert Parameter Value From A String To A Int32

Comment: so everytime we use parameter method we need to convert

Comment: kindly see if this is correct? cmd.Parameters.Add("@Enumber",SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtEnumber.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Inumber",SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtInumber.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pnumber",SqlDbType.VarChar,20).Value = Convert.ToString(txtPassport.Text);

Comment: Could you add the schema of your table? Something is not what it seems here.

Comment: [dbo].[Employee](
 [Enumber] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Inumber] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Pnumber] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Fname] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Mname] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Sname] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Age] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Bdate] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Gender] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Mstatus] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Nationality] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Eaddress] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [Cnumber] [int] NULL,
 [Picture] [varchar](max) NULL,

Comment: Instead of leaving a comment click [edit] to add extra info to your question. We are not a forum.

Comment: Okay, I was wrong, seems like the sqlparameter does indeed do the conversion from `string` to `int` (or at least `SqlDbType.Int`) on itself.

Comment: @Corak however you were right from the start outlining the necessity of a parsing approach to correctly read the integer values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is caused by one or more of your TextBox used to fill an Int parameter being empty. In this case the internal code that tries to convert your string value assigned to an Int parameter will fail. This happens only at the execution time not at the assignement because the Parameter.Value property is defined as object.

A possible workaround could be

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Employee(Enumber,Inumber,Pnumber,.....)";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Enumber",SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
     string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEnumber.Text) ? "0" : txtEnumber.Text ;
```

But this is not a good solution because your user could type anything in those textboxes. So you really should add a validation level before attempting the insert and add a real integer as value.

```
int enumber;
if(!Int32.TryParse(txtENumber.Text, out enumber))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Type a number");
   return;
}

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Enumber",SqlDbType.Int).Value = enumber;
```

This applies to other textboxes as well.